# AVPlayer - change AVPlayerLayer while playing

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I have a `UICollectionView` where each cell contains an `AVPlayer` and `AVPlayerLayer`. When a cell is selected, the video is blown up to full-screen through a new view controller with an `AVPlayerLayer` of its own. I do this very similar to how [this guy](http://zappdesigntemplates.com/uiviewcontroller-transition-from-uicollectionviewcell/) does it. The new `AVPlayerLayer` is hooked up to the `AVPlayer` instance, and that way, it magically keeps on playing in the new view controller. This all seems like kind of a mess, and my problem is that while I'm animating the presentation of the full-screen view controller, the video pauses for about a second before continuing playback.

Is there a better way to perform an `AVPlayerLayer` handoff like this? That is, to play a video in a cell, and then have that same video keep on playing in a new view controller that is presented. Worth noting is that I never dismiss the view holding the `UICollectionView`, so I shouldn't have to worry about the `AVPlayer` instance being released while watching full-screen.

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to have the full-screen AVPlayerLayer in a new view controller? Because other wise you could just animate the view of the AVPlayerLayer to full-screen dimensions in the same viewcontroller. No handoffs of any sort required that way.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. This is because the full-screen view has more things than the AVPlayerLayer attached to it.